# Ajax with jquery, scriptmanager and webservice which return null

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, scriptmanager

I dont get from my WebService data back and I dont know why. :/

I have in my MasterPage.master this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager id="scriptMng" runat="server">
         <Services>
             <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebServices/Mailing.asmx" />
         </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="mailFormUpdatePanel" updateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
              /* form */
         </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my Mailing.asmx I have this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Services/Mailing.cs" Class="Mailing" %>
```

In my Mailing.asmx.cs I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Mailing
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://ktwebstudio.cz/WebServices/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Mailing : System.Web.Services.WebService 
{

    [WebMethod()]
    public string Mail(string fromName, string fromSurename, string fromEmail, string fromPhone, string phoneTimeFrom, string phoneTimeTo, string selectedJob, string mailMsg) 
    {
        if (fromName.Trim() != "" && fromSurename.Trim() != "" && fromName != "Jméno" && fromSurename != "Příjmení" && fromEmail.Trim() != "" && fromEmail != "E-mailová adresa (povinné)")
        {
            bool error = false;
            if (fromPhone.Trim() != "" && fromPhone != "Telefonní číslo (nepovinné)")
                error = !IsNumber(fromPhone.Trim());
            if (IsWord(fromName.Trim()) && IsWord(fromSurename.Trim()) && IsEmail(fromEmail.Trim()) && !error)
            {
                /*
                some logic
                */

                try { client.Send(mail); }
                catch
                {
                    return "Odesílání zprávy selhalo, zkuste prosím akci opakovat. <br />Při přetrvávajících problémech zkuste použít alternativní způsob kontaktování, který naleznetev sekci <a runat=\"server\" href=\"<%$RouteUrl:RouteName=contact%>\">kontakt</a>.";
                }
                return "Zpráva byla úspěšně odeslána, děkujeme.";
            }
            else
                return "Vaše jméno, příjmení nebo jeden z Vášich vyplněných kontaktů obsahuje neplatné znaky.";
        }
        else
            return "Musíte vyplnit Vaše jméno, příjmení a kontaktní email.";
    }

    public bool IsWord(string word)
    {
        Regex mask = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Zá-žÁ-Ž]*$");
        return mask.IsMatch(word);
    }
    public bool IsEmail(string email)
    {
        Regex mask = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return mask.IsMatch(email);
    }
    public bool IsNumber(string number)
    {
        int num;
        return int.TryParse(number, out num);
    }
}
```

So In my Masterpage.master.cs I test if browser support JS, if not i call web service from OnClick method where is this and i think that this was OK: (Dont ask me why I dont wanna have this if JS isnt supported)

```
Mailing mail = new Mailing();
statusMsgLbl = mail.Mail(txtName.Text, txtSurename.Text, txtMail.Text, txtPhone.Text, startTime.SelectedValue, endTime.SelectedValue, selectJob.SelectedValue, txtMessage.Text);
```

But if JS is supported (i hope that user have it turn on) I have in my Masterpage.master this jQuery and javascript code:

```
    var msg;
    Sys.Application.add_load(load);
        function load() {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
           msg = Mailing.Mail($('#txtName').val(), $('#txtSurename').val(), $('#txtMail').val(), $('#startTime').val(), $('#endTime').val(), $('#selectJob').val(), $('#txtMessage').val());  
        });
    }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestHandler);
        function beginRequestHandler() {
            $(document.createElement('div'))
                        .attr('id', 'overlay')
                        .width($('#formBox').width())
                        .height($('#formBox').height())
                        .css({ backgroundImage: 'url(/Static/Img/bc_overlay.png)', position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, margin: "5px", textAlign: "center", color: "#000", display: "none" })
                        .append("<div id='loading' style='padding-top:100px'><strong>Odesílám</strong><br /><img src='Static/Img/ajax-loader.gif' width='33px' height='33px' alt='loading' /></div>")
                        .show(500)
                        .prependTo($('#formBox'));
            $('#formBox').css('position', 'relative');
        }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
    function endRequestHandler() {
       $('#loading').delay(2000).slideUp(800);
       $('#overlay').append("<div style='padding-top:100px'><strong id='statusMsg'></strong></div>");
       if (msg != null)
          $('#statusMsg').css('display', 'none').delay(2800).fadeIn(300).text(msg);
       else
          $('#statusMsg').css('display', 'none').delay(2800).fadeIn(300).text("Problém");
       $('#overlay').delay(6000).hide(800);                                     
    }
```

**First function use my WebService.**

**Second function do some cool things when is beginRequest.**

**And last function do some cool things too when is endRequest + write error / success message**.. But i dont get my strings from Mailing.asmx.cs and I dont know why. :-/ I put into last function if(msg != null) ... So **I know that msg is null** and if u can tell me why, i will so grateful.

(I tried it by $.ajax in jquery too, but i got 500 ERROR so I use this way with Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest that you check below points to troubleshoot:

1. First see if there are not any java-script errors. IE8 has developer tools that allow you script debugging or you can use Firefox & Firebug combo for the same.
2. Check request/responses going from/to browser - use tools such Fiddler (or Firefox/Fiebug)
3. There can be problem in your *cool* logic - so try to put `alert` in your js code to see what code points are getting invoked. Of course, you can actually use any script debugger (including visual studio) to add break-points and step through. If you are not aware, you can use `debugger;` statement in your js to trigger debugger - browser will prompt you with available debuggers to attach.

As such, I prefer using jquery ajax method. Here are couple of articles to help you to start with it: http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/  and http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1127-consuming-web-service-webmethod-from-jquery-in-aspnet-.aspx